# Multiple inheritance in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, inheritance

I have a contract `C` that `is Ownable` so I can use `ownerOnly` on its admin functions.
Recently, I added some functionality that I'm going to start using in other projects. I refactored the functionality out to a second contract `Refactored`, so now `contract C is Refactored, Ownable`.

But then I discovered that some of the functionality of `Refactored` needs to be protected as well, so I added `contract Refactored is Ownable` and everything broke with a `Linearization of inheritance graph impossible` error.

I ended up leaving `Ownable` on `Refactored` and removing it from `C` - and that solved it - but now it looks like `C` is using `ownerOnly` functionality without including `Ownable` - i.e. it works, but doesn't look good.

Is there any way I can have both contracts be `Ownable` and still have one of them inherit the other? (I'd like to avoid having a variable in `C` be of type `Refactored` because then I'll have to expose a bunch of getter functions, negating the whole refactoring).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I ended up leaving Ownable on Refactored and removing it from C - and that solved it - but now it looks like C is using ownerOnly functionality without including Ownable

I don't know why you'd think that. That's how inheritence works in pretty much any object-oriented language. If B is A's child and C is B's child, A is C's parent.

To answer your question, no, there's no way of doing what you're trying to do. You'll have to do with how it is currently.